# Keep variables after leaving activity

Tags: android

I am trying to find a way to keep my variables constant throughout the life of the app.  The way I have designed the app is that a user clicks on a class and submits a grade.  What i would like is for the app to store the grade after the activity has been closed.  When the user backs out of the screen and goes back in, he must reenter the grade he got.

The code for my pages are as follows:

Class Choice Activity

```
public class ClassCore extends Activity {

    TextView eng101, eng102, mat186, com173;
    TextView eng101scr, eng102scr, mat186scr, com173scr;
    LinearLayout eng101bg, eng102bg, mat186bg, com173bg;
    Button coreReturn;
    int ss;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.classcore);

        eng101bg = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.eng101bg);
        eng102bg = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.eng102bg);
        mat186bg = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mat186bg);
        com173bg = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.com173bg);

        eng101 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.eng101);
        eng102 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.eng102);
        mat186 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mat186);
        com173 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.com173);

        eng101scr = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.eng101CoreScr);
        eng102scr = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.eng102CoreScr);
        mat186scr = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mat186CoreScr);
        com173scr = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.com173CoreScr);

        coreReturn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCoreRtrn);


        eng101.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i = new Intent(ClassCore.this, Eng101.class);
                i.putExtra("grades", "eng101" );
                startActivityForResult(i, 1);
            }
        });
    }

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(data.getExtras().containsKey("e101FinalScore")){
            eng101scr.setText(data.getStringExtra("e101FinalScore"));
            eng101bg.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00FF00"));
        }}
```

English Activity

```
public class Eng101 extends Activity {

    Button btnSubmit;
    EditText userGrade;
    String strGrade;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.eng101);

        btnSubmit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnE101);
        userGrade = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.eng101Scr);

        btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                strGrade = userGrade.getText().toString();
                Intent i = getIntent();
                String msg = i.getStringExtra("grades");
                if(msg.contentEquals("eng101")){
                    i.putExtra("e101FinalScore", strGrade);
                    setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
                    finish();
                }               
            }
        });     
    }   
}
```

Comment: you mean when user opens the app the next time also the grade must be same?

Answer (score 2):

In 3 way you can achieve your function.

**1. Global Variables**

You can use global variable by defining any variable with modifier `public static` like

```
public static String GRADE = "10";
```

You can use it in any class in the app by `CLASS_NAME.GRADE`. Like

```
String grade = CLASS_NAME.GRADE;
```

**Note: it will loose its value when you close the app.**

**2. SharedPreference**

For retaining value after app closes, you need to use `SharedPrefeernce` or SQLite database.

Here is the example of how to use [SharedPreference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).

Initialize SharedPreference as below in your activity

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("app_name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Get value from SharedPreference as below

```
String grade = sp.getString("grade", "0");
```

Set value to SharedPreference as below

```
sp.edit().putString("grade", "5").commit();
```

**3. SQLite**

You can use [SQLite](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary.html) database to store your own structure data. You can create different tables and store/retrive date according to your requirements. Here is some examples: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use SQLite to store your data.

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SharedPreferences file to store variables as key value pairs when the user is about to exit the activity (onPause) and when the activity is re-created you can read the data from that Shared preferences file.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref